# Angular UI Calendar with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, angular-ui

I'm using the following versions:

1. Angular UI Calendar 1.0.0
2. FullCalendar 2.1.1
3. jQuery UI 1.10.4

I'm having an issue with jQuery UI conflicting with the calendar. My events can't be dropped and the options on the calendar are ignored such as height.

If I comment out the jQuery UI library the calendar works fine but the issue is that jQuery UI is being used in other parts of the application. Is there a work-around to solve this issue or do I need to be on a specific version?

I'm going to keep tinkering but wanted to see if anyone in the community has resolved this.

Comment: I ended up upgrading jQuery UI to 1.11.4 and no longer had any conflicts.

Comment: Thats great! I was going to say, JQueryUI has it's own Calendar, so the issue might have been in compatibility between the two different libraries. But I'm glad its working for you now!